# android.os.MessageQueue.next taking up the plurality of exclusive time -- is this normal behavior?

Tags: android, performance

I've recently run a method tracing session on the process of opening a FragmentActivity that takes about 750-1000ms to open from the previous activity and has a ListView into which it loads its initial batch of data in times that vary from as low ("low") as 1500ms to as high as 5000ms. After sorting by "exclusive time", I noticed that a method named `android.os.MessageQueue.next` is taking up the plurality of the time.

A view of all the main thread after a method tracing session. Notice `android.os.MessageQueue.next` is first in the list:

[image: A view of all the threads after a method tracing session]

Now, my question is as such: is this standard operating procedure in an Android app--that is, does `android.os.MessageQueue.next` refer to the main queue waiting for another operation? Or, alternately, could this indicate some sort of temporary deadlock?

Should I be worried?

Comment: Have you created any handlerthread inside your code and using it during initial phase?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a library that does. @7383

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a handler thread hopefully something went wrong. I could see these lines in source code of MessageQueue's next method. Have a look it may help you to understand.

** Message next() 
{ // Return here if the message loop has already quit and been disposed. // This can happen if the application tries to restart a looper after quit // which is not supported. **

[Source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/MessageQueue.java)